# Biboptions in Natbib giving error with article class

Tags: natbib

I was trying to use the command `\biboptions{numbers,sort&compress}` for compressing references. I am using `natbib` package which alone does not give any error, but when I activate `biboptions` command an error occurs. This `biboptions` command does not give any error when used in `elsarticle` template of Elsevier or `svjour3` of Springer, and it compresses references very well. But why does the error occur only when the default article template is used?

Example code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{natbib}
\biboptions{numbers,sort&compress}
\begin{document}
\title{Type Title Here}
\author{Author's name}
\date{}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
Type abstract here
\end{abstract}
\section{Introduction}
\cite{bell3,bell6,bell7,bell8,bell9,bell10,bell11,bell12,bell13}
     \bibliography{My.Bibtex.Library}
   \bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\end{document}
```

Comment: \biboptions is a special command of elsarticle (and perhaps svjour3, I don't have the class, so couldn't check). It is not defined for article.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: `\usepackage[noadjust]{cite}` served my purpose.